# f continuous and goes to $0$ at $\infty$ then$f\in L^1 (R)$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that if f continuous and goes to $0$ at $\infty$ then f is Lebesgue function?

I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=\cases{1,&$ -1<x<1$\cr 1/|x|,  &\text{otherwise}  }$.

Comment: +1, I was about to write down exactly the same example ;) - but reason for my comment: are there some similar obvious examples for $f\in C^1, C^2...$ or does the thesis actually hold, if $f$ is often enough differentiable?

Comment: @Fant You could "smooth out" the function above at $x=\pm 1$ so that it becomes infinitely differentiable.  Or you can start with the function 
$$f(x)=\cases{ 1-\text{exp}\bigl[  -{1\over x^2}\text{exp}(-{1\over(1-x)^2})\bigr], &$0<x<1$\cr 1,&$x\le 0$\cr 0, &$x\ge 1$}.$$ This is infinitely differentiable, with derivative $0$ outside the interval $(0,1)$. Suitably scaling this function will give you an infinitely  differentiable function with any desired constant value on $(-\infty,n)$ and any other desired smaller constant value on $[n+1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Fant You can "paste" a bunch of these  together to obtain a counterexample that is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: "smoothin" out was my idea, but didn't see directly how. 2nd example looks nice, i will check this .. ty

Comment: But probably, someone more clever than myself can come up with a simpler counterexample...